# Unable to intercept traffic on android application using burp suite

Tags: android, chrome, burp-suite

When I try to intercept the traffic through burp suite, the app itself won't load. This doesn't happen in some applications like Chrome and Gmail but happens on YouTube and other applications. It shows that there is no internet connection but I can still surf the internet through Chrome.

Comment: "app won't load" or "app won't connect to the internet?" You suggest both, but which is it? What does Burp say? What packets are captured?

Comment: Have you installed the Burp root certificate?